# jquery fadein wont work on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fadein

I have a span wrap in a td. I set my span css to display none. When trigger my js function to display using fadein, it won't work on IE8 but works perfectly on 7 and 9. Below is my code.

CSS code

```
.noansError{border: 1px solid #a51b1b; padding: 0 0 0 2px; background: #f8a1a1; color: #a51b1b; font-size: 14px; display: none;}
```

HTML code

```
<td><span id="errorNoAns1" class="noansError">Please Answer</span><input id="q1" type="text"/></td>
```

MY jquery

```
$('#q1').css('display','none');
$('#errorNoAns1').fadeIn(300);
```

id **errorNoAns1** is the span that wont fadein on ie8

Comment: How are you testing IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whew! Ive got it, after a few hours of twiks and searching. I found out the you need to have a relative position on you parent element. I just added position relative on my td where the span is wrap.

Answer (score 1):

I think jQuery's fadeIn(), fadeOut() function can only show/hide block element, you can set the .noansError{ display:block } to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#q1').hide()
```

ie has some problem about attribute setting

Answer (score 0):

`$('#errorNoAns1').hide().fadeIn(300);` might fix it, but it's a bit hacky.

Comment: do you have an example page online I could see

Comment: sorry but i dont have live example.